# Getting "Signature validation failed. SAML Response rejected" using python-saml with flask

Tags: python, flask, saml-2.0

I'm getting the following error when trying to process a IdP-initiated SAML2 response using python-saml and flask:

```
Signature validation failed. SAML Response rejected
```

I'm following the example [here](https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml/blob/master/demo-flask/index.py). My code is:

```
url_data = urlparse(request.url)
req = {
    "https": "on",
    "http_host": request.host,
    "server_port": url_data.port,
    "script_name": request.path,
    "get_data": request.args.copy(),
    "post_data": request.form.copy()
}
auth = OneLogin_Saml2_Auth(req, custom_base_path=app.config['SAML_PATH'])
auth.process_response()
```

In SAML_PATH, I have the following in my `settings.json` file:

```
{
    "strict": false,
    "debug": true,
    "sp": {
        "entityId": "[spEntityId]",
        "assertionConsumerService": {
            "url": "[acsUrl]",
            "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
        },
        "NameIDFormat": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified",
        "x509cert": "[x509cert]",
        "privateKey": "[privateKey]"
    },
    "idp": {
        "entityId": "[idpEntityId]",
        "singleSignOnService": {
            "url": "http://dummy.com/saml2",
            "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
        },
        "singleLogoutService": {
            "url": "http://dummy.com/saml2",
            "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
        },
        "x509cert": "[x509cert]"
    },
    "security": {
        "nameIdEncrypted": false,
        "authnRequestsSigned": false,
        "logoutRequestSigned": false,
        "logoutResponseSigned": false,
        "signMetadata": false,
        "wantMessagesSigned": true,
        "wantAssertionsSigned": true,
        "wantNameIdEncrypted": false,
        "requestedAuthnContext": false
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've used dummy values for the IdP singleSignOnService and singleLogoutService URLs. I don't think I need them in my case as I just need to process the SAML Response. I've also using the same x509cert for both the SP and IdP. The response has a signed message and encrypted assertion:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="[Destination]" ID="[ID]" IssueInstant="2015-11-30T15:35:02.702Z" Version="2.0">
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        [Issuer]
    </saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="[ID]" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" />
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="[ID]" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" />
                    <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                        <xenc:CipherValue>
                            [CipherValue]
                        </xenc:CipherValue>
                    </xenc:CipherData>
                </xenc:EncryptedKey>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <xenc:CipherValue>
                    [CipherValue]
                </xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </saml2:EncryptedAssertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

I've verified that the x509cert and privateKey are correct. I'm new to SAML2, so I'm hoping it's something simple :) Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Did you find the fix? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: My issue was resolved by having the IdP include the KeyInfo element in the Signature. This is currently required by python-saml: https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml/issues/101

Answer (score 3):

The response you provide above isn't signed, but you've requested that that response be signed, therefore you software is rejecting the response.

Your configuration says `wantMessagesSigned`, and `wantAssertionsSigned`. The Assertions are signed (maybe -- we can't actually tell from your example), but the message (i.e., the response as a whole) is not signed.

How can you tell? If your response were signed, it would look more like the following -- note the `ds:Signature` block (which I've included some blank lines around to make it easier to see). The block includes a DigestValue of the message, and then a Signature of that Digest. It includes the Certificate with which you can decode the signature and verify it matches the digest.

The IdP signs the response with **its** private key and sends you the certificate. Assertions are encrypted using **your** certificate by the IdP, allowing you (and only you) to decrypt them (Are the encrypted assertions signed? I don't know -- need to decrypt them first.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="[Destination]" ID="[ID]" IssueInstant="2015-11-30T15:35:02.702Z" Version="2.0">
<saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    [Issuer]
</saml2:Issuer>

<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-cl14n#"/>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
    <ds:Reference URI="#[ID]">
      <ds:Transforms>
         ...
      </ds:Transforms>
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www/s3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
      <ds:DigestValue>[DigestValue]</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
  </ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:SignatureValue>
     [Signature]
  </ds:SignatureValue>
  <ds:KeyInfo>
    <ds:X509Data>
      <ds:X509Certificate>
         [Certificate]
      </ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
  </ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>


<saml2p:Status>
    <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
</saml2p:Status>
<saml2:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="[ID]" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" />
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="[ID]" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" />
                <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <xenc:CipherValue>
                        [CipherValue]
                    </xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedKey>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <xenc:CipherValue>
                [CipherValue]
            </xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
</saml2:EncryptedAssertion>
```